# Why are pending map tasks not starting?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I have a particular pig job that usually takes around 12 minutes to run but a couple of times a day it gets stuck in an odd state. The job has 6 maps and 1 reduce task. It successfully completes the first map task and then it stays "on hold" for hours (forever!). The job tracker indicates there are 5 maps and 1 reduce pending, however no tasks are running. No tasks show any errors. The map tasks will simply not start but no errors occur.

How can I figure out why are the tasks not starting?

I have tried increasing the jobs priority and I have verified that there are available map and reduce slots. The task log for the one map that ran looks completely normal. Is there some other log somewhere that would tell me what is going on?

I am using Cloudera CDH4.5 with MR1. The small cluster has 5 nodes.

Comment: Just to be sure... Is there a Combiner?

Comment: According the pig logs there is no combiner.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the log for the first map task - it has probably failed. I've run into a number of situations where the first map tasks fails, yet is reported as successful and none of the subsequent map tasks ever start.

Comment: The one map that ran shows a positive map input and output record count. The task log at the bottom indicates "Starting flush of map output", "is done. And is in the process of commiting" and "Task attempt done". I cannot find any exception or error in the whole map task log. It looks like a successful map task.

Comment: I had the same issue (when exporting my tables to S3). I found the solution based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747427/hadoop-yarn-job-is-getting-stucked-at-map-0-and-reduce-0 I have commented memory configurations in mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml and restarted my master (single node).